# data tables get whole table order

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

DataTables documentation says that in order to reorder rows you do something like this.

```
mytable.on('row-reorder', function ( e, diff, edit ) {
    var table = [];

    for ( var i=0, ien = diff.length; i < ien; i++ ) {
        var curData = mytable.row( diff[i].node ).data();
        curData[0] = diff[i].newPosition;
        table.push(curData);
    }
});
```

My question here is how could I loop through all rows and not just the ones that are affected cause I would like to send the whole table then to the server.

Right now I only send rows that were affected with the reorder.

An example:

I start with this:

```
ID | Data
2  | row 2
3  | row 3
1  | row 1
```

Then I drag row with ID = 1 to top row (replace ID=1 with ID=2)

What I want to get out as result of that function is a table that will contain this:

```
ID | Data
1  | row 1
3  | row 3
2  | row 2
```

How can I extend this?